# How can I get the value from another form

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, web

now i'm trying to get the value from another form. But i don't know how to make it.

This is my first form:

[image: click to see]

and this is method, when we click submit in the the form1, the page will redirect to this method.

```
public function input_data_inserted()
{
    $id_data_inserted = $this->input->post('id_data_inserted');
    $date = $this->input->post('date');
    $id_data = $this->input->post('id_data');
    $amount= $this->input->post('amount');
    $id_room = $this->input->post('id_room');

    $passed = FALSE;

    $checkIdData = $this->modelku->cek_idData()->result_array();
    $checkIdRoom = $this->modelku->cek_idRoom()->result_array();

    foreach ($cekIdData as $cID) 
    {
        foreach ($cekIdRoom as $cIR) 
        {
            if ($id_data == $cID['id_data'] && $id_room == $cIR['id_room']) 
            {
                $data = array 
                (
                    'id_data_inserted' => $id_data_inserted,
                    'date' => $date,
                    'id_data' => $cID['id_data'],
                    'amount' => $amount,
                    'id_room' => $cIR['id_room'],
                );

                $this->modelku->input_data($data, 'table_data_inserted');
                $data['table_data_inserted'] = $this->modelku->show_data('table_data_inserted')->result();
                $this->modelku->increase_value($amount, $id_data);
                //redirect to second form
                redirect('admin/Data/data\view_detail_data');

                $passed = TRUE;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if(!$passed)
    {
        echo "ERORR";
    }
}
```

And this is my second form:

[image: click to see]

Method for second form:

```
public function input_detail_barang()
{
    $id_data = $this->input->post('id_data');
    $no_inv = $this->input->post('no_inv');
    $condition = $this->input->post('condition');

    $data = array 
    (
        'id_data' => $id_data,
        'no_inv' => $no_inv,
        'condition' => $condition
    );

    //I need amount from first form, because i will use it. How can i do?


}
```

Any Solution? Thx

Comment: Is your problem solved or not?

Comment: yes, thx u brother :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After this line you can save it to session:

```
$data = array (
    'id_data_inserted' => $id_data_inserted,
    'date' => $date,
    'id_data' => $cID['id_data'],
    'amount' => $amount,
    'id_room' => $cIR['id_room'], // You missed single quote here      
);
$this->load->library('session');
$this->session->set_userdata("Firstformdata",$data);
```

And for show this data add this line:

```
$this->session->userdata("Firstformdata");
```

Comment: hi i try your method, and i rewrite my seccond form like this https://pastebin.com/K08YLKYP

Comment: No its wrong bcoz it has a full array. you have to print like that https://pastebin.com/EikcTPy4 and if its not working than print_r($amount); and see the array.

Comment: Glad to help :)

Comment: Hi @Anand Pandey can u help me to solve this problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47310660/how-to-looping-redirect-the-same-page-depends-on-value

Comment: I am at home now will solve tomorrow .Sorry for today